# Can't exit from game play loop after a replay (while loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
# Rock paper Scissors

import random


# Setting computer to choose random numbers from 1-3

def computer_option():

    computer = random.randint(1,3)

    if computer == 1:
        computer = 'r'
    elif computer == 2:
        computer = 'p'
    elif computer == 3:
        computer = 's'

    return computer

#Asking player to choose rock , paper or scissors

def user_option():

    ask = input("'rock', 'paper', and 'scissors' " )

    if ask in ['r','rock', 'Rock', 'R']:

        ask = 'r'

    elif ask in [ 'p', 'P' , 'Paper', 'paper']:

        ask = 'p'

    elif ask in ['s' , 'scissors', 'S', 'Scissors']:
        ask = 's'

    else:

        print('Sorry')

    return ask



#THE GAME STARTS HERE!!!!!!


def game_starts():

    player_score = 0

    computer_score = 0

    while player_score != 10 and computer_score != 10:

        player = user_option()

        computer = computer_option()

        if player == 'r':

            if computer == 'p':

                print(f'computer paper attacks player rock')

                computer_score += 1

            elif computer == 's':

                print(f'player rock attacks computer scissors')

                player_score += 1

        elif player == 'p':

            if computer == 's':

                print(f'computer scissors attacks player paper')

                computer_score += 1

            elif computer == 'r':

                print(f'player paper attacks computer rock')

                player_score += 1

        elif player == 's':

            if computer == 'r':

                print(f'computer rock attacks player scissors')

                computer_score += 1

            elif computer == 'p':

                print(f'player scissors attacks computer paper')

                player_score += 1



        print(f'player {player_score}') # Printing out Player's Score

        print(f'computer {computer_score}')# Printing out Computer's Score


        # announcing the winner


        if player_score == 10:` `

            print('player won')

        else:

            print('computer won')




game_starts()


#Asking the player to play the game again

def play_again():

    again = input('play the game again? Yes/No ')

    if again in ['yes', 'Yes' , 'y' , 'Y']:

        again = 'y'

    elif again in ['no', 'No', 'n', 'N']:

        again = 'n'

    return again


replay = play_again()

while replay == 'y':  #Asking user for a replay 

    game_starts()

    if replay == 'n':

        break
```

Comment: You need to call `play_again` inside your loop as well - otherwise you're only ever asking the user once (before the loop).

Answer (score 0):

If you look in this part of the code

```
replay = play_again()

while replay == 'y':  #Asking user for a replay 

    game_starts()

    if replay == 'n':

        break
```

The game starts again, then ends by displaying the scores of the player and the computer. But after that the program comes to this line :-

```
if replay == 'n':

    break
```

but at this point the value of replay is still 'y' as the value hasn't been changed after the execution of the game for the second time, so the while loop goes on and on. Basically you need to do call the function play_again() every time after you print the game scores.

Comment: Sorry, Can you just elaborate please?